# Приложение крешится на ios 9.2.1 если установить через Testfligh или крашлитику или ipa

Tags: ios, swift3

Суть проблемы в том что при установке по шнурку в debug или release режиме все работает хорошо, но если билд залить через крашлитику или testflight или просто через ipa то приложение крешится на разных моментах. На каких конкретно не понятно, логи с крашлитики не описывают точной картины.

Приложение написано на swift 3.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180a89bdc objc_msgSend + 28
1  Foundation                     0x181d3114c -[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression dealloc] + 52
2  Foundation                     0x181da9758 empty + 72
3  Foundation                     0x181d05528 -[NSConcreteMapTable dealloc] + 108
4  Foundation                     0x181d4d0e4 -[NSISEngine dealloc] + 84
5  UIKit                          0x1860f7d70 -[UIView dealloc] + 624
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180a91ae8 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 508
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1812ed42c _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1813bea20 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1812ed680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
10 GraphicsServices               0x1827fc088 GSEventRunModal + 180
11 UIKit                          0x186164d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
12 Drool                          0x10010e890 main (AppDelegate.swift:18)
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x180e8e8b8 (Missing)``
```

Comment: логи все таки покажите

Comment: Обновил, это один из

Comment: из крэшлитика посмотрите все потоки, крэшится что то другое, просто он не понимает что, по этому дает вам неправильную инфу

Comment: А там на всех крешах не понятно в каком потоке и из за чего крешится. Я если честно в замешательстве потому что подобное вижу впервой.

Comment: ну вы покажите, и будем думать

Comment: Возможно это проблема компилятора. Могу посоветовать два варианта. Первый вариант: идите **Edit Scheme** -> **Run** -> **Build configuration** -> **Release** и тогда установить приложения и возможно увидите, где оно падает. Второй вариант изменить настройки компилятора Swift: **Build Settings** -> **Swift Compiler - Code Generation** -> **Optimization Level** -> **none**. Но я не знаю насколько это хорошее и долгосрочное решение

Comment: Я пробовал и то и другое и ничего не помогло, В итоге откатился до стабильной версии и начал накатывать функционал и так дебажил до того момента пока не начало падать и тогда я понял где собака зарыта. Но это все мелочи. Основная проблема не решилась, почему то приложение не стабильно именно через TF. Ну то есть сейчас оно стабильно, но кто знает что это не повториться.

Comment: @АлексейЗаякин , все же опишите эти мелочи в ответе, может кому пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблема оказалась в картинке *png*, которая была в формате *rgb 1998*.